# Joining MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

in my database there are 2 tables : posts, room

Posts tables include ID and Title columns and includes many rooms and hotels titles and IDs.

In the room table there are 3 columns : room_id, hotel_id and price where room_id and hotel_id are from Posts table.(ID column)

I want to run a query so I can see Hotel title, Room title, room_id(ID) and price in one table.

I can't figure out the correct join command. what code should I use?
thank you

[image: MYSQL]

Comment: can you please share a sample data set for all the tables ?

Comment: @trillion I've added an image

Comment: @pooya 1st it looks like the design of the database can have a big improvement, rooms and hotels should be in separate tables if you need many to many joining. 2nd sample data means text not images, see [how to produce a minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Shmiel well I didn't design the database and I can't change it nor intend to I just want to select the data and export it. the image have sample data and the problem is self-explanatory. guess it's a Many to one ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description (if it would have featured some sample data it would have been easier) you can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM room r INNER JOIN posts p ON r.room_id = p.ID
```

Additionally I´d give matching columns similar names.